# Concatenating multiple cells in one column based on condition on list of strings in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given a spreadsheet where we have columns as follows:

```
A,     ..., P,     ..., S,                   ...
Test1, ..., Name1, ..., Test1, Test2, Test3, ...
Test2, ..., Name2, ..., Test3,               ...
Test3, ..., Name3, ..., Test1, Test3,        ...
```

I would like to create a list of values from Column P where A is in the list S1. For example, for the column A value `Test1`, a new column T would contain the following: `Name1, Name3` because `Test` appears in both rows in S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Excel MS365 formula**:

I feel like the following could point you in the right direction:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(B1:B3,ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&a&",",", "&C1:C3&","))))))
```

---

**PowerQuery**:

If you don't have access to above mentioned functions, consider to work your way around this using PowerQuery, a powerfull tool to do this quite elegantly too:

[image]

Here the column 'custom' is created through:

```
= let s=[Column1], c2=Table.Column(Source, "Column2"), c3=Table.Column(Source, "Column3") in Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Numbers(0,List.Count(c2)), each if List.Contains(Text.Split(c3{_},", "),s) then c2{_} else null),", ")
```

The completed M-code could look like:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Ans = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each let s=[Column1], c2=Table.Column(Source, "Column2"), c3=Table.Column(Source, "Column3") in Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Numbers(0,List.Count(c2)), each if List.Contains(Text.Split(c3{_},", "),s) then c2{_} else null),", "))
in
    Ans
```

Obviously I've used fictional column names, just make sure to edit the above to suitable named table and columns.

Comment: Great solution @JvdV, I am wondering about which scenario you want to include adding concatenation. I checked the following works too: `=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(B1:B3,ISNUMBER(FIND(a, C1:C3))))))`. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal thanks, I anticipated this sample data might work, however I always like to prevent possible false positives.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV, I was trying another alternative, but your solution is shorter and at the end I could not avoid using a LAMBDA array helper function: `=BYROW(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A1:A3,TOROW(C1:C3))), TOROW(B1:B3),""), LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",,x)))`